# Not able to verify Robotium license key

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, robotium

I am new in Robotium testing. I have the Robotium license key. My robotium 10 shots are over. So doing testing using Robotium I get a window to verify the license key. I entered the license key but it showing some message on the top of that window.

```
Could not connect to the server. Please check your internet connection and try again.
```

I checked my connection. It is working fine. But still getting this error I dont know.

*I am usingRobotium Recorder 2.0.24* and 
*Android Developer Tools    22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508*

One more thing I want to know.... is Robotium License key is PC dependent ? means Can we use one license key in 2 or more PC ?

Answer (score 0):

The license is per user. We updated the Robotium servers today and probably that is why you could not reach it. Please try again. If it doesn't work it could be that you are behind a proxy and then the below link might help you.

http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/

Comment: I m getting the same message